# Creating correlation matrix for multiple combinations of variables

Tags: python, statistics, correlation, pearson-correlation

I have a csv file with 10 columns. I can use pandas to import the dataframe and use the corr() function to output a matrix heatmap. What I want to achieve next is for the code to loop through the dataframe and find high or low correlations between **combinations of columns**

For example, the simple correlation matrix looks at:

A:A, A:B, A:C, A:D etc

But I want the code to combine columns, in every conceivable way, such as:

AB:A, AB:B, AB:C, AB: D etc
ABC:A, ABC:B, ABC:D etc

And if there are any noticeable correlations between certain combinations, to highlight those.

Is this possible at all? Or are there proprietary applications that can do this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I assume with "combination" you mean linear combination. You can loop over the columns (not the most elegant way) and use sklearn linear_model

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from sklearn import linear_model

df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.random([10,10]),columns=['A','B','C','D','E','F','G','H','I','J'])

for i,col1 in enumerate(df):
    if i > 0:
        X = df.iloc[:,0:i]
        for j,col2 in enumerate(df):
            if j >= i:
                y = df[[col2]]
                regr = linear_model.LinearRegression()
                regr.fit(X, y)
                score = regr.score(X,y)
                print(f'X: {X.columns} y: {y.columns} score:{score}')
```